# update with same name to Alfresco

Tags: java, methods, alfresco

i want to update a file to Alfresco, but when Alfresco has a file with the same name it takes exceptions "duplicate child name".
Can i update files with the same names and keep all of them. For example i upload the file with name "fileNew" and then i try to upload again a file with the same name exactly (so they have only different versions to Alfresco)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are in fact not updating but trying to create a child which already exists. Alfresco requires child names to be unique (have a look at `contentModel.xml`)

```
  <type name="cm:folder">
     <title>Folder</title>
     <parent>cm:cmobject</parent>
     <archive>true</archive>
     <associations>
        <child-association name="cm:contains">
           <source>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </source>
           <target>
              <class>sys:base</class>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </target>
           <duplicate>false</duplicate>
           <propagateTimestamps>true</propagateTimestamps>
        </child-association>
     </associations>
  </type>
```

Make sure to use the "update" (in old web-client) or "upload new Version" in share and not "add content" or "upload".